# Where is the appropriate place to discuss epistemology of secondary sources and/or encyclopedic websites for philosophy?

Tags: discussion

Where is the appropriate place to discuss epistemology of secondary sources/encyclopedic websites such as: Wikipedia, Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy; etc.?

This is a multi-disciplinary field encompassing a wide a variety of fields, such as information science, data science, philosophy, research methods; etc.

If such a question of this manner were posted in Philosophy site of Stack Exchange, how would this question differ if it were posted in another website of Stack Exchange, [such as the Statistics website of Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)?

---

**Prior Research**:--

- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology_of_Wikipedia)
- (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemology-social/)
- Jankowski, Steve (2013). *[Wikipedia and encylopaedism: A genre analysis of epistemological values](http://%20Wikipedia%20and%20encylopaedism:%20A%20genre%20analysis%20of%20epistemological%20values)* (PDF) (M.A.)., 27 May 2013.
- (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_of_Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would vote to leave open such questions on this site if the questions were specific enough to be answered with minimal personal opinion, especially if someone answered the question providing references.

Based on your first search link such questions seem relevant:

> Epistemology is a major branch of philosophy and is concerned with the nature and scope of knowledge. The epistemology of Wikipedia has been a subject of interest from the earliest days of its existence.
>
> Early analysis related the epistemology of Wikipedia to social epistemology. Other realms of epistemological research; epistemology of testimony, and epistemic value theory have been addressed with reference to Wikipedia.

However, questions are generally [closed](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) if five people [with the privilege to vote](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) vote to close them.

Asking and answering questions are a way for all those involved, even just readers, to learn more about the topic. I don't know the answers to such questions myself, but I would be interested in reading the answers you might receive.

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, June 24). Epistemology of Wikipedia. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 12:20, July 5, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Epistemology_of_Wikipedia&oldid=903169654

Comment: I would slightly more emphasize that the answers should be written in good faith to further Stack Exchange's goals, civility, and ethics. This is a wonderful response!  The fact that answers should be  free of personal opinion is an important point. :) :D